# RStudio crashes with RCpp with reproducible codes

Tags: r, rcpp

@user3759195 wrote a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322356/rstudio-crashes-and-it-does-not-reproduce about RStudio crashing with RCpp, but didn't give any reproducible case. @KevinUshey mentioned in the comments that we have to `PROTECT` the `wrap` within the code.

I took the liberty of posting two alternatives to `split.data.frame` function written in RCpp:

*** VERSION THAT DOES NOT CRASH RSTUDIO ***

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
List splitDataFrameCpp(DataFrame x,NumericVector y) {
  int nRows=x.nrows();
  int nCols=x.size();

  std::map<double,vector<double> > z;
  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    std::vector<double> tmp=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (x[i]);
    for (int j=0;j<nRows;j++) {
      z[y[j]].push_back(tmp[j]);      
    }
  }

  std::vector<double> yunq=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (sort_unique(y));
  std::map<double, DataFrame> z1;
  for (int i=0;i<int(yunq.size());i++) {
    NumericVector tmp1=wrap(z[yunq[i]]);   // *** DEFINING INSIDE LOOP ***
    tmp1.attr("dim")=Dimension(int(tmp1.size())/nCols,nCols);
    DataFrame tmp2(wrap(tmp1));   // *** DEFINING INSIDE LOOP ***
    tmp2.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
    z1[yunq[i]]=tmp2;
  }
  return wrap(z1);  
}
```

*** VERSION THAT CRASHES RSTUDIO ***

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
List splitDataFrameCpp(DataFrame x,NumericVector y) {
  int nRows=x.nrows();
  int nCols=x.size();

  std::map<double,vector<double> > z;
  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    std::vector<double> tmp=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (x[i]);
    for (int j=0;j<nRows;j++) {
      z[y[j]].push_back(tmp[j]);      
    }
  }

  std::vector<double> yunq=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (sort_unique(y));
  std::map<double, DataFrame> z1;

  NumericVector tmp1;    // *** DEFINING OUTSIDE LOOP ***
  DataFrame tmp2;    // *** DEFINING OUTSIDE LOOP ***

  for (int i=0;i<int(yunq.size());i++) {
    tmp1=wrap(z[yunq[i]]);
    tmp1.attr("dim")=Dimension(int(tmp1.size())/nCols,nCols);
    tmp2=wrap(tmp1);
    tmp2.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
    z1[yunq[i]]=tmp2;
  }    
  return wrap(z1);      
}
```

The main difference between the two codes is that in one case `tmp1` and `tmp2` is defined within the loop, and in the other case outside the loop.

1. Can anyone explain why the second loop crashes (and what can be changed to NOT make RStudio crash)?  I'm still a newbie to C++ and primarily writing RCpp by looking at examples on SO or the RCpp gallery website - so would like to understand this behavior a little more.
2. Also, as a side benefit, if anyone can recommend changes to make the code faster, that will be great. The code that does NOT crash is currently around 2x-3x times faster than R's `split.data.frame` function based on some test cases I used.

Example of test case:

```
> testDF
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1  5  4  1  3  2
2   2  1  5  4  1  3
3   2  2  1  5  4  1
4   3  2  2  1  5  4
5   1  3  2  2  1  5
6   4  1  3  2  2  1
7   1  5  4  1  3  2
8   2  1  5  4  1  3
9   2  2  1  5  4  1
10  3  2  2  1  5  4
11  1  3  2  2  1  5
12  4  1  3  2  2  1

> testSp<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,3,3,5)

> split(testDF,testSp)     OR  > splitDataFrameCpp(testDF,testSp)     
$`1`
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  5  4  1  3  2
2  2  1  5  4  1  3
3  2  2  1  5  4  1

$`2`
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
4  3  2  2  1  5  4
5  1  3  2  2  1  5
6  4  1  3  2  2  1

$`3`
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
7   1  5  4  1  3  2
10  3  2  2  1  5  4
11  1  3  2  2  1  5

$`4`
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
8  2  1  5  4  1  3
9  2  2  1  5  4  1

$`5`
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
12  4  1  3  2  2  1
```

The `microbenchmark` result for this test case:

```
> microbenchmark(t1<-split(testDF,testSp),t2<-splitDataFrameCpp(testDF,testSp))
Unit: microseconds
                                   expr     min      lq   median       uq      max neval
             t1 <- split(testDF, test2) 343.181 365.562 372.8760 387.9430 1027.786   100
 t2 <- splitDataFrameCpp(testDF, test2) 177.881 190.315 200.5545 208.4545  870.093   100
```

*** EDIT ***

Added the `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] microbenchmark_1.3-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.1 tools_3.1.0
```

Also, testDF was created as a `numeric` in R, not `integer`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to generate a reproducible example -- can you add in a few missing pieces? 1. `sessionInfo()`, 2. How is `testDF` constructed (are the columns integer or numeric?) FWIW, the second version you posted does not crash for me with Rcpp 0.11.2, R 3.1.0 on Mac OSX Mavericks, RStudio 0.98.943.

Comment: FWIW it does not crash either for me, either in or out of RStudio;

Comment: Good post, and good comments. A truly reproducible example does need a data set (including its creation, or a `dput()` call), and the example invocation.

Comment: @KevinUshey, added the `sessionInfo` and `testDF` is numeric. May be its a Windows version of RStudio issue?

Comment: @RomainFrancois, would it be possible for you tell me which OS did you use?

Comment: I can replicate your segfault with `Rcpp 0.11.1`, so my suggestion is to update to the latest version of `Rcpp` on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) (which is now (0.11.2)

Comment: @KevinUshey, yes, same result on my end. after the update it no longer crashes.

Comment: Same as Kevin. I'm using a mac running the current version of OSX,  Current R, Current Rcpp, Current RStudio.

Comment: Ditto here. 'Current whatever', Rcpp from git and hence marginally ahead from CRAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it is worth, here is a complete example you can just `sourceCpp()`.  And similar to what Kevin and Romain noted, it does not blow up for me either.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List splitDataFrameCppA(DataFrame x,NumericVector y) {
  int nRows=x.nrows();
  int nCols=x.size();

  std::map<double,vector<double> > z;
  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    std::vector<double> tmp=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (x[i]);
    for (int j=0;j<nRows;j++) {
      z[y[j]].push_back(tmp[j]);      
    }
  }

  std::vector<double> yunq=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (sort_unique(y));
  std::map<double, DataFrame> z1;
  for (int i=0;i<int(yunq.size());i++) {
    NumericVector tmp1=wrap(z[yunq[i]]);   // *** DEFINING INSIDE LOOP ***
    tmp1.attr("dim")=Dimension(int(tmp1.size())/nCols,nCols);
    DataFrame tmp2(wrap(tmp1));   // *** DEFINING INSIDE LOOP ***
    tmp2.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
    z1[yunq[i]]=tmp2;
  }
  return wrap(z1);  
}


//[[Rcpp::export]]
List splitDataFrameCppB(DataFrame x,NumericVector y) {
  int nRows=x.nrows();
  int nCols=x.size();

  std::map<double,vector<double> > z;
  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    std::vector<double> tmp=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (x[i]);
    for (int j=0;j<nRows;j++) {
      z[y[j]].push_back(tmp[j]);      
    }
  }

  std::vector<double> yunq=Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> > (sort_unique(y));
  std::map<double, DataFrame> z1;

  NumericVector tmp1;    // *** DEFINING OUTSIDE LOOP ***
  DataFrame tmp2;    // *** DEFINING OUTSIDE LOOP ***

  for (int i=0;i<int(yunq.size());i++) {
    tmp1=wrap(z[yunq[i]]);
    tmp1.attr("dim")=Dimension(int(tmp1.size())/nCols,nCols);
    tmp2=wrap(tmp1);
    tmp2.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
    z1[yunq[i]]=tmp2;
  }    
  return wrap(z1);      
}


/*** R

testDF <- read.table(textConnection("
1  5  4  1  3  2
2  1  5  4  1  3
2  2  1  5  4  1
3  2  2  1  5  4
1  3  2  2  1  5
4  1  3  2  2  1
1  5  4  1  3  2
2  1  5  4  1  3
2  2  1  5  4  1
3  2  2  1  5  4
1  3  2  2  1  5
4  1  3  2  2  1
"))

testSp <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,3,3,5)


str(splitDataFrameCppA(testDF, testSp))
str(splitDataFrameCppB(testDF, testSp))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(split(testDF,testSp),
               splitDataFrameCppA(testDF,testSp),
               splitDataFrameCppB(testDF,testSp))

*/
```

The benchmark is about even between your two version:

```
R> library(microbenchmark)

R> microbenchmark(split(testDF,testSp),
+                splitDataFrameCppA(testDF,testSp),
+                splitDataFrameCppB(testDF,testSp))
Unit: microseconds
                               expr     min      lq  median      uq      max neval
              split(testDF, testSp) 687.271 724.748 745.287 791.574 2373.283   100
 splitDataFrameCppA(testDF, testSp) 380.781 393.161 406.686 421.469  491.803   100
 splitDataFrameCppB(testDF, testSp) 377.959 393.391 405.476 429.947 2052.193   100
R> 
R>
```