# Subsetting a data.frame in Rcpp by id yielding 'not compatible with request type'

Tags: r, dataframe, rcpp

I have a problem with my Rcpp function. I basically have a data frame (dimension `N*K`) and a numeric vector (dimension `H < N`) as input, and as output I'd like to return a data frame (dimension `H * M`) having the same row index of the integer vector.

DATA FRAME:

```
val1 val2 val3 val4
1   0.2059  A   14
2   0.5700  B   61
3   0.5354  C   24
4   0.8123  D   78
5   0.7542  E   39
6   0.6433  F   17
7   0.2452  G   96
8   0.2557  H   93
9   0.7208  I   36
10  0.2565  L   12
```

INTEGER VECTOR:

```
2
4
7
10
```

OUTPUT:

```
2   0.5700  B   61
4   0.8123  D   78
7   0.2452  G   96
10  0.2565  L   12
```

Here's my code. Thanks in advance for your help:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame matchRows(DataFrame &OriginalDF, NumericVector &ReducedVector)
{
  int nr1 = OriginalDF.nrows(), nc1= OriginalDF.size();
  int nr2 = ReducedVector.size();

  if (nr1 < nr2) throw std::range_error("Size of data frame has to be higher     than the target random subset!");

  std::map<double, DataFrame> X;
  for (int j = 0; j < nr2; j++)
  {
    NumericVector tmp1=wrap(OriginalDF[ReducedVector[j]]);
    tmp1.attr("dim")=Dimension(int(tmp1.size())/nc1,nc1);

    DataFrame NewDF(wrap(tmp1));
    NewDF.push_back(OriginalDF[ReducedVector[j]]);
    NewDF.attr("names")=OriginalDF.attr("names");

    X[ReducedVector[j]] = NewDF;
  }
  return wrap(X);
}
```

The previous version of my code unfortunately caused RStudio to crash. Ideally there's some way to initialize the data frame to zero and then add up values using `push_back()`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame matchRows(DataFrame &OriginalDF, NumericVector &ReducedVector)
{
  int nr1 = OriginalDF.nrows(), nc1 = OriginalDF.size();
  int nr2 = ReducedVector.size();

  if (nr1 < nr2) throw std::range_error("Size of data frame has to be higher than the target random subset!");

  DataFrame NewDF;
  for (int j = 0; j < nr2; j++)
  {
    NewDF.push_back(OriginalDF[ReducedVector[j]]);
  }
  return NewDF;
}
```

Comment: Provide the complete error message and indicate which line of your code throws the error. Then do some debugging, i.e., check if all variables (in particular those you assign or convert) have the type you expect them to have.

Comment: The Rcpp script runs without errors. However, when I call the function in r it gives me the message error: 'not compatible with request type'.

Comment: I tried to debug it following the exemple [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353078/rstudio-crashes-with-rcpp-with-reproducible-codes), but I still get the same problem in RStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so what you are really trying to do here is just subset the `data.frame` by row ids in Rcpp.

e.g.

```
D[c(2,4,7,10),]
```

First up, in your code you define:

```
std::map<double, DataFrame> X;
```

There is no `wrap()` conversion to deal with an object of this type. Furthermore, wrap really shouldn't be used in this case as it is auto converted due to the return type specified by the function.

To subset a data.frame, efficiently, do not use the `.push_back()` feature since it always requires a full copy and, thus, is not very efficient.

Instead, you want to use the `idx` variable and [Rcpp vector subsetting](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/) like so:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// Extract rows from data.frame object in Rcpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame matchRows(Rcpp::DataFrame D, Rcpp::IntegerVector idx) {

  // First, break apart each vector
  Rcpp::IntegerVector   val1 = D["val1"];
  Rcpp::NumericVector   val2 = D["val2"];
  Rcpp::CharacterVector val3 = D["val3"];
  Rcpp::NumericVector   val4 = D["val4"];

  // We assume that the index passed in starts at 1. 
  // Hence, we need to adjust the idx to start at 0 with:
  idx = idx - 1;

  // Next up, create a new DataFrame Object with selected rows subset. 
  return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("val1")  = val1[idx],
                                 Rcpp::Named("val2")  = val2[idx],
                                 Rcpp::Named("val3")  = val3[idx],
                                 Rcpp::Named("val3")  = val4[idx]
                                 );
}

/*** R
# Make some data
set.seed(1337)
D = data.frame(val1 = 1:10, 
               val2 = rnorm(10), 
               val3 = letters[1:10], 
               val4 = sample(1:100, 10),
               stringsAsFactor=FALSE)

# Create index that starts at 1 instead of 0. 
# This will be converted in the C++ function.
idx = c(2,4,7,10) 

matchRows(D, idx)

*/
```

The devil in the details is we reduce the index by 1 to account for C++'s indices starting at 0 vs. R's 1 before calling the index. This can be handled within the C++ code as well. Though, I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is fine. I hope there was another way to avoid expliciting the names of the variables, as for a numeric matrix.