# RStudio keeps crashing with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'd like to understand what is making this program crash. I've seen at least three related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353078/rstudio-crashes-with-rcpp-with-reproducible-codes), [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/rcpp-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg07667.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768796/rstudio-crashes-after-calling-an-rcpp-function-multiple-times), but I haven't found a clear answer addressing the issue, so here's is some sample code to replicate the problem.

**The R code:**

```
library(Rcpp)

Rcpp::sourceCpp("myfunction.cpp")

data1      <- rnorm(2000)
data2      <- rnorm(2000)

mydata <- matrix(cbind(data1, data2), nrow=2000, ncol=2)
values <- log(1:6)

for (i in 1:1000) {
  myfunction(values, mydata)
}
```

**The C++ code:**

```
#include "Rcpp.h"
#include "math.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double myfunction(const NumericVector& theta, const NumericMatrix& data) {

  double ans = 0;

  int theta_size = theta.length();
  NumericVector mytheta(theta_size);

  int data_size = data.nrow();
  NumericMatrix mat(data_size, 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < theta_size; i++) {
    mytheta(i) = exp(theta(i));
  }

  if ( true ) {  // Flow control

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
      mat(i, 1) = pow(data(i-1, 1), 2) + mytheta(1)*mat(i-1, 1);
      ans = ans + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
      mat(i, 2) = pow(data(i-1, 2), 2) + mytheta(4)*mat(i-1, 2);
      ans = ans + 1;
    }

  }

  Rcout << "Ok!\n";

  return ans;
}
```

Everything works fine *at least the first time* I use `myfunction()`, but it then crashes when called within the R for loop. I reinstalled R, Rtools and RStudio (on Windows) to see if maybe something was wrong with the installation, but I still face the same issue.

This is making the seamless integration between R and C++ less seamless that I first thought, and since I've seen that I'm not the only one who's been facing this issue, it looks like we are all making some *obvious mistake* when starting with Rcpp (at least on RStudio), but what is it?

Essentially, I want to be sure I'm not missing something completely obvious here because all the answers I've seen so far seem to imply that it is the case.

**Note**: this is a shortened version of a longer function I've been testing with Rcpp, the original version seems to work fine the first *few* times I call it, but it also eventually crashes.

Update: removed rm(), oops.

Comment: I recommend you include versions, at least: R, RStudio, and `Rcpp`. Better yet, `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a repaired version with

- @HongOoi's correction to the loop index
- my correction to the columns
- R code in the C++ file
- no outout from C++ code called N times
- output at end
- seeding the RNG to make it reproducible

#### Code

```
#include "Rcpp.h"
#include "math.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double myfunction(const NumericVector& theta, const NumericMatrix& data) {

  double ans = 0;

  int theta_size = theta.length();
  NumericVector mytheta(theta_size);

  int data_size = data.nrow();
  NumericMatrix mat(data_size, 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < theta_size; i++) {
    mytheta(i) = exp(theta(i));
  }

  if ( true ) {  // Flow control

    for (int i = 1; i < data_size; i++) {
      mat(i, 0) = pow(data(i-1, 0), 2) + mytheta(1)*mat(i-1, 0);
      ans = ans + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < data_size; i++) {
      mat(i, 1) = pow(data(i-1, 1), 2) + mytheta(4)*mat(i-1, 1);
      ans = ans + 1;
    }

  }

  //Rcout << "Ok!\n";

  return ans;
}

/**** R
set.seed(123)
data1      <- rnorm(2000)
data2      <- rnorm(2000)

mydata <- matrix(cbind(data1, data2), nrow=2000, ncol=2)
values <- log(1:6)

for (i in 1:1000) {
  myfunction(values, mydata)
}
cat("Success\n")
*/
```

#### Demo

```
edd@rob:~$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/trusky.cpp")'

R> set.seed(123)

R> data1 <- rnorm(2000)

R> data2 <- rnorm(2000)

R> mydata <- matrix(cbind(data1, data2), nrow = 2000, 
+     ncol = 2)

R> values <- log(1:6)

R> for (i in 1:1000) {
+     myfunction(values, mydata)
+ }

R> cat("Success\n")
Success
edd@rob:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < data_size; i++) {
>   mat(i, 1) = pow(data(i-1, 1), 2) + mytheta(1)*mat(i-1, 1);
>   ans = ans + 1;
> }
> ```

When `i == 0`, you try to access `data(-1, 1)` and things go pear-shaped from there. The fact that it didn't crash the first time you ran it just means you got lucky (or unlucky, in that it lured you into a false sense of confidence).

Comment: Spot on.  Also @coatless often makes the point that the RcppArmadillo containers can help here as you can turn checks for out-of-bounds access on.

Comment: Also, ` NumericMatrix mat(data_size, 2);` means you can only access columns 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.